# Issue displaying 3 cols on ipad bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="boxTop"></div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="/Content/Images/YogurtImages_280x135/ProductPicture.png" width="280" height="135" alt="Danone Ultimate blueberry yogurt" class="productMarginTop">

                    <p style="display: block; height: 40px; text-align: center; line-height: 45px; color: #00386a; font-size: 24px;  font-family: Foco-Regular;">
                        BLUEBERRY
                    </p>
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #00386a; width: 85%; margin:0 auto"></div>
                    <h5 style="color: #00386a; font-size:19px; cursor:pointer; width:260px" class="text-center" id="nutritionInfo" data-productid="1" data-colorcode="#00386a" data-productname="BLUEBERRY">
                        <span class="text-center" style="margin-left:14%">NUTRITIONAL INFO</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span>
                    </h5>
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #00386a; width: 85%; margin:0 auto"></div>
                    <h5 class="text-center" id="findStore" style="width:260px">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="1" style="color: #00386a;font-size:19px;text-decoration: none;" class="text-center">
                            <span class="text-center" style="margin-left:14%">FIND A STORE</span> <span id="chevvy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                    <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                <p class="text-center" style="color: #00386a">
                                    Woolworths
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-center" style="color: #00386a">
                                    Independent Retailers
                                </p>
                                 <p class="text-center" style="color: #00386a">
                                    Aldi
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #00386a; width: 85%; margin:0 auto"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="boxBtm"></div>
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

The above is produced in a foreach loop so the overall HTML when the loop has finished would be something like this

```
<div class="row col-xs-12">
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row col-xs-12">
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

When I view this on a mobile phone they are stacked one per row which looks great, the problem I have when viewing this on a ipad it appears as the following

[image]

They are over lapping each over, there should be a space between each one like this

[image]

I can't figure out what is wrong with the HTML? if its doing this because of space how can I make it wrap two products per row?

** Update **
Below is the result of what was mentioned using col-md-4 col-md-6 when viewing on the ipad
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
<div class="row col-xs-12">
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row col-xs-12">
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4  col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4  col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4  col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried what you have suggested, when viewing on a desktop (large screen) it shows two per row, I need three per row when vieweing on the desktop, when I minimize the browser I still get the over lapping issue

Comment: ok you have to switch `sm` to `md`, i'll fix the example to hopefully clearify the issue

Comment: that sorted the desktop, but when I view this on the ipad it now shows one product per row which leaves alot of space to the right hand side of the product (I've attached a picture to my question showing this)

Comment: I thought I could pass the notion through example; anyway the point is ipad respond to `col-xs*` so depending on how much width you want it to occupy on ipad you'll use the `col-xs*`  selector  grid.Try switching all these to `col-xs-6`  and you'll have 2 per row.

Comment: the fact that they overlay is caused by vertical spacing, you can either increase height of element or add margins/padding